# iPhone 5s camera takes random size photos

Tags: iphone, photos

My iPhone 5s camera takes random size photos. Sometimes they are large and at other times they are postage size images.  Any answers ?

Comment: I believe we will need some more details. Is there any steps you could post to reproduce the problem, or is it completely random? Also, are these pictures in the default Photos app? Do you use iCloud Photo Library?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I went out to the outskirts of town and took a few nature photos. I returned home and downloaded them and they opened up around 2" x 3" each at 100%. I went out to my backyard and took a few more just to see what would happen. Same thing although maybe 4" x 5" this time. Still very small. Then I took a photo of my desk. This time it opened up and when at 100% I could only see about 25% of the image on my screen so it was a very large image. I don't know why it's doing this but I'm guessing it's trying to adapt (erroneously) to different lighting?

Comment: Any chance you emailed them to yourself?

Comment: yes all are emailed thats the only way I know to get them to my computer. I haven't had this problem before though or at least not this much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a logical explanation for the problem and although, I can't guarantee, in this case it *is* the problem, I think there is a high probability.

When you select to email a photo, after you tap send, you are prompted with sizing (compression) options like this:

[image: phone scaling options]

You can choose one of the options and as most things in life, everything has a trade off. If you select anything *but* "Actual Size", it will compress your photo, and the size it then comes in at will be smaller than what you would have expected. "Actual Size" is massive on all but the older iPhones. Full size it big, but likely will fit on a monitor, and the "Medium" and "Small" sizes are just like you described.

This is not "lossless" compression like you see sometimes and does what it needs to with the image to reduce the actual file size.

For transferring images to your computer, AirDrop is the easiest way but only works if you have a Mac. If you use a PC, you could consider using [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455?locale=en_US) to download Photostream images (which should be quite high resolution, if not natural size), or there is always the old faithful [Image Capture](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I do appreciate your answers.

Comment: I don't get prompted as you describe above. It just send and I get what I get when I get back to my computer. I did the same thing today with my sons and when we got back they were all postage stamp size images. I again went out to my back yard took a photo. Same lighting conditions . Sent it to my email and viola a huge image. Go figure. Many moments will be lost.

Comment: I can't find a setting area for the camera anywhere that has anything to do with photo sizes.

Comment: That is certainly odd. Have you considered an alternative way of transferring the images? Also, I'd be curious what the results would be if you would download the Camera+ app or similar and then email them from there. You can import the images into the app and then send them from there. Are you using the default mail app for sending the images?